# Can browse using IP address but cannot browse using URL

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, silverlight, web-applications

I am here because I have a problem installing a web application, here is the situation:
1. We are installing a web application which is supposed to be accessible from both internet and intranet. 
2. Now we can only browse it using the ip address of the server in our internal website (intranet).
3. It cannot be browsed if using the URL with /***.aspx file, but available with URL/***.html. For example, it is not available using http://test.mycompany.com/Default.aspx. However, it is available using http://test.mycompany.com/test.html.
In other words, all the .asp file are not accessible, but html is ok.

I don't have much knowledge in this field, just follow the installation guide provided by the supplier. Can someone help me to solve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please put a screen shot here

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to enable ASP.NET in IIS.

On your web server, open up IIS Manager, in the left-hand pane select your web server, in the content pane, in the group labeled "IIS", find the  the tile labled "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions".  Double-click on that to open it.

You should see a list of ISAPI and CGI extensions.  Ensure that ASP.NET is set to "Allowed".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I already did that. Under ISAPI and CGI extension, ASP.NET is set to "Allowed". But still cannot work...

Comment: One more information, I also cannot ping the URL on the server, but I can ping URL from my own Desktop... Anyone can help me?....

Comment: When you say you cannot ping the URL, what exactly do you mean?  Can you provide an example?  Are you able to ping the server's IP address?  Are you able to ping test.mycompany.com?